# Facebook scenario 5 on the Removal of offline_access permission page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have a general Facebook development question. I'm trying to understand how scenario 5 on Facebooks Removal of offline_access page is supposed to work and what that token can be used for.

A little bit about my app. I allow my apps users to schedule/post Facebook posts from a third party system I integrate with. We then pull the likes and comments and feed it back into that system. Right now we are set up to get the 60 day long lived token and that works great but we have to impose a time limit on scheduling. It's not the end of the world but if we can do better we want to explore that option.

Thus we were told about "Scenario 5" which I've posted and linked to below. My questions are:

1. What does it mean by a page that the user administers?
2. What are the pros/cons of this method?
3. Similar to #2 what can this method do or not do that the 60 day access token can't/can do?
4. Any tips or hurdles to watch out for when implementing this?

Scenario 5: Page Access Tokens

When a user grants an app the manage_pages permission, the app is able to obtain page access tokens for pages that the user administers by querying the [User ID]/accounts Graph API endpoint. With the migration enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.

Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to the [Page access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) which are used by your app to administer a [Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/help/pages) on behalf of an admin of that page.

These tokens can only access the page itself, or publicly accessible content, you can't use a page access token as a replacement for a user access token.